# ASP Core Intercept All Authentication Requests

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4

**EDIT**
I'm looking for a generic way to intercept authentication requests, there should be a way to globally configure this, using middle-ware or events etc, unrelated to the framework that I am using(IdentityServer4)

I'm using IdentityServer4 to Authenticate my WebApi.  I'm looking for events to intercept authentication requests post and prior to authentication.

My startup class is configured this way to handle authentication.

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

    ApiName = "api1"
});
```

I'm looking for an event for post authentication, so that I can create a link from IdentityServer4 Users to local users so I can foreign key there references.

Is there an event or an easy way to plug into Post_Authentication_Requests, and authenication requests in general, I would like to do some additional logging of failed login attempts as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, most of the authentication middleware have a way to hook into their respective authentication events. These can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/Events/OpenIdConnectEvents.cs). To answer your question thought, there are a few PRE and POST auth event hooks, you will need to pick one that satisfies your needs. example:

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

    ApiName = "api1",

    Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents() 
    {
        OnMessageReceived = async context =>
        {
            //example of a "before" event hook
        }

        OnTokenValidated = async context =>
        {
            //example of an "after" event hook
            var claimsIdentity = context.Ticket.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (claimsIdentity != null)
            {
                // Get the user's ID
                string userId = claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            }
        }
     }
});
```

You can also see an example in the samples repo of aspnet/Security [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/OpenIdConnectSample/Startup.cs#L86), where they demonstrate how they hijack a failed authentication request to return a 500 (and not the normal 401)

Comment: I'm trying to do two things, add new users to my DB if this is the first time they are being logged in from IdentityServer4, I should use the OnTokenValidated Correct?  Also, I'm trying to log the IP Of attempted logins, should that be the OnMessageReceived Event, or is there a better place to do so?

Comment: I have implemented the OnMessageReceived event to alter something like:
x.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
                    {
                        OnMessageReceived = c =>
                        {
                            if (c.HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest && c.Request.Query.ContainsKey("Authentication"))
                                c.Token = c.Request.Query["Authentication"];
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
but it never enters the function call when I debug.